# In android Translate-Animation how to Translate view1 above the another view2, both view exits in different layout

Tags: android, animation

Suppose i have one view say it as image1 like,

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

So now,i am working with android animation Translate and it is possible to Translate image4 on to the position of image3 because they are in same parent, but i want to Translate image3/image4 on to the position of image1/image2 which is in different parent.... i have tried every layout...

Comment: By transform if You mean that you want to set image3 in the ImageView which has currently image1...then it is very much possible just use set image resource API in your code  on the basis of condition. I don't see any problem there.

Comment: sorry my mistake...i mean that i am working with **TranslateAnimation** of android i just want to translate image3 from their current position to position of image1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

layout property clipChildren="false" works fine for me....

Answer (score 0):

Man. Create one general `LinearLayout` which will contains these 4 `ImageViews`. And then create in code create `TranslateAnimation` which will do path from one image to another. You must get the coordiantes of your first image(start point) and move it to second image(second point). Like overlay.

Comment: my above question is just the minimization of my real question... i am working with may images and layout so in my real project its not possible to take all images in one layout....

Answer (score -1):

```
View flipper can be used for the same.

 <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="6dip" >
<LinearLayout1

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout2

</LinearLayout>

        </ViewFlipper>
and inside code viewFlipper.showNext(); to move between views
```

Comment: please try to understand my question.. i am working with **TranslateAnimation** so i want to translate view so view flipper is not solution...