# View animate going behind other layout

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to animate a view to another layout, but i got an issue, because my view is behind the layout. I tried put `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`, but without success.
My code:
layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="#ffffff">

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My activicty class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

        float x = 300;
        float y = 300;
        RadioButton button = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        button.animate().setDuration(10000).x(x).y(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: The LinearLayout is above your RadioButton.

Comment: By "to another layout" you mean you want your `RadioButton` to become a child of your `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Yes, but dont forget that i want the animation. So, it to go from one layout to another

Answer (score 10):

The items will be drawn in the same order as they are ordered in the layout. For your layout, the RadioButton will be draw first and then the LinearLayout. If they are overlapping, the LinearLayout will be drawn over the RadioButton.

**Solution Part #1:**
Flip the order of RadioButton and LinearLayout so that the RadioButton is always drawn last.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/final_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:background="#ffffff">
</RelativeLayout>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton" />
```

A more rigorous explanation on the [Android Developer's site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html).

**Solution Part #2:**
Unrelated to the point I made above but probably equally important, you need to start the animator. Updated source below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RadioButton mRadioButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

        float x = 300;
        float y = 300;

        ViewPropertyAnimator animator = mRadioButton.animate().setDuration(10000).x(x).y(y);
        animator.setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationEnd");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
        })
        animator.start();
    }

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
}
```

Tested, animates on app startup in Android 5.1.

Answer (score 5):

just give all **xml** layout element property as  `android:clipChildren="false"` & `android:clipToPadding="false"`. and don't forgot to do  `animatedView.bringToFront()`

have same problem before month and found solution after working hard couple of days. find my que. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319866/in-android-translate-animation-how-to-translate-view1-above-the-another-view2-b)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve, but if you are moving a child `View` outside its container you need to disable the `clipChildren` and `clipToPadding` attributes on the container in order to see the child moving outside the parent:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
        ...
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Anyway, if you are experiencing **z-order** problem on some view you can use the `bringToFront()` method; in your case:

```
    final RadioButton button = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    button.animate().setDuration(10000).x(x).y(y).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            button.bringToFront();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me provide you the solution with respect to the **480X854** pixels mdpi screen

[image: 480X854 pixel screen]

Scenario 1: You want RadioButton to cross over the LinearLayout with RelativeLayout as parent ViewGroup than **you need to fix your z-order**.Make the changes as below layout.The animation starts from the point A(0,0) to point C(300,300) wrt the RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">
    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
    />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Scenario 2: You want RadioButton to animate on the LinearLayout with LinearLayout as parent ViewGroup than you need to set layout as below. The animation starts from the point B(20,20) (as per the `layout_margin` value) to point D(320,320) wrt the RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Scenario 3: You want RadioButton to animate across the LinearLayout with LinearLayout as parent ViewGroup and your x or y value goes beyond the LinearLayout boundaries size in either direction e.g. x=800 > 480 pixels OR Y=1200 > 854 pixels

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <!-- Allow all the children to go out of their parent boundaries -->
    android:clipChildren="false"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    <!-- Allow all the children to go out of their parent boundaries -->
    android:clipChildren="false"
    <!-- Do not clip the children at the padding i.e. allow to children go 
    beyond the padding -->
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope that helps...
Happy Coding...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment by sir Karaokyo which you responded to then i suggest this is what you want

```
RadioButton r1; // suppose you already referenced it
LinearLayout l1; //    //
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.abc_slide_in_top);
 // the R.anim. blah blah is the preferred animation you want
//when the time comes
if(r1.getParent() != null)
     ((ViewGroup)r1.getParent()).removeView(r1);
l1.addView(r1);
r1.startAnimation(anim); 
// you can create an animation listener and add the view when the animation
//starts
```

The catch here is, it will look like the way you wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is try to relayout in xml so that RadioButton is shown after LinearLayout.

Call bringchildTofront(yourradiobutton) before starting the animation 
or
If you want more control on the drawing order then Extend RelativeLayout and override

```
protected int getChildDrawingOrder (int childCount, int i)
```